# componentDidMount doesn't render a component when the page is loaded

Tags: reactjs

I'm using the moviedb api to receive two lists with movies and tv shows. I have two buttons which switch one list to another. 
When the page is loaded I want to show the movie list and change it to the tv shows list by clicking on the tv show button. The problem is when the page is loaded there is not the movie list but when I click on the button to see the tv list
it shows and when I click on the movie button the movie list appears.

I've tried to use different lifecycle methods but they didn't work correctly. I guess the component receives an empty array and doesn't show anything. How it could be solved?

```
class AdditionalActorInfo extends Component {
  state = {
    actor: [],
    isMovieClicked: true,
    isShowClicked: false
  };

  onMovieClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      isMovieClicked: true,
      isShowClicked: false
    });
  };

  onShowClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      isShowClicked: true,
      isMovieClicked: false
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props;
    if (!id) {
      return;
    } else {
      fetch(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/${id}?api_key=81f382d33088c6d52099a62eab51d967&language=en-US`
      )
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.setState({
            actor: data
          });
        });
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { actor, isShowClicked, isMovieClicked } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="actorInfo-container">
         <div className="buttons">
            <button onClick={this.onMovieClick}>Movies</button>
            <button onClick={this.onShowClick}>TV Shows</button>
          </div>
        {isMovieClicked ? (
              <MovieCredits id={actor.id} />
            ) : isShowClicked ? (
              <ShowCredits id={actor.id} />
            ) : null}
          </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AdditionalActorInfo;
```

```
class MovieCredits extends Component {
  state = {
    movieCredits: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props;
    if (!id) {
      return;
    } else {
      fetch(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/${id}/movie_credits?api_key=81f382d33088c6d52099a62eab51d967&language=en-US`
      )
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          const movieCredits = data.cast
            .map(item => {
              return (
                <li key={item.id} className="credit-list">
                  {item.release_date.slice(0, 4)}

                  <p>
                    <Link to={`/movieInfo/${item.id}`}>
                      <span>{item.title}</span>
                    </Link>
                    {item.character !== "" ? `as ${item.character}` : null}
                  </p>
                </li>
              );
            });
          this.setState({
            movieCredits
          });
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { movieCredits } = this.state;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ul>{movieCredits}</ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default MovieCredits;
```

```
class ShowCredits extends Component {
  state = {
    showCredits: [],
    isLoading: true
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props;

    if (!id) {
      return;
    } else {
      fetch(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/${id}/tv_credits?api_key=81f382d33088c6d52099a62eab51d967&language=en-US`
      )
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log(data);
          const showCredits = data.cast
            .map(item => {
              return (
                <li key={item.id} className="credit-list">
                  {item.first_air_date.slice(0, 4)}

                  <p>
                    <Link to={`/movieInfo/${item.id}`}>
                      <span>{item.name}</span>
                    </Link>
                    {item.character !== "" ? `as ${item.character}` : null}
                  </p>
                </li>
              );
            });
          this.setState({
            showCredits,
            isLoading: false
          });
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { showCredits } = this.state;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ul>{showCredits}</ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default ShowCredits;
```

Comment: In componentDidMount of AdditionalActorInfo `const { id } = this.props;` Whats the id? Are you passing this as prop, i think you forgot to pass `id` and thats why the rest of the code is not being called in `componentDidMount`

Comment: You can simply add a `console.log` after the `.then()`. This way you can be sure if certain `fetch` is called or not. You have couple of `if` statement which prevents you to proceed with the `fetch`. Normally `html` are coded inside `render()`, but in your case, you code the `html` inside `response`. If this is the case, you have to add additional state to trigger the `fetch` and `render` again.

Answer (score 0):

react setstate is asynchronous by default you have to make it synchronous by calling setstate  inside fetch method.
it should look like this:
.then(data => () => this.setstate({}))